# Updating iOS App without Downloading Update from App Store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I have an app that gives users recommendations based of a set of infrequently updated static values. It doesn't make sense to put them into a database and make calls constantly as the values change on a once per month basis, if even that. I would however like to be able to update these values every so often without needing to push a new version of the app. Could I put a file in AWS and have the user download it through the app or something along those lines? I'd love to hear other examples/solutions!

Just as an example, the MTG Trades app behaves similarly in that every 2-3 months you're able to download lists of newly released cards and other information associated with them.

Comment: Yes.  You will need your app to check your server for updated data each time it starts (or perhaps save the date of the last check and check once per day or whatever).  This check should be fairly quick and use little data, then your app can download all of the data if it has been updated.

Comment: Fabric have Optimizely which can change constant variable for you at run time, so you can use it also